# How to read a .txt file in a batch script on a network?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, batch, echo

I'm making a little game because I was bored and I want it to work in a LAN network, my map files are in a shared file. When I try to echo the contents nothing comes out.

Here is the code:

```
( 
    echo %personage%
) > %path%p1.txt

set /p p1=<%path%p1.txt

set /p p2=<%path%p2.txt

set /p p3=<%path%p3.txt

set /p p4=<%path%p4.txt

set /p p5=<%path%p5.txt

set /p p6=<%path%p6.txt

set /p p7=<%path%p7.txt

set /p p8=<%path%p8.txt

set /p p9=<%path%p9.txt

set /p p10=<%path%p10.txt

set /p p11=<%path%p11.txt

set /p p12=<%path%p12.txt

echo %p1%%p4%%p7%%p10%

echo %p2%%p5%%p8%%p11%

echo %p3%%p6%%p9%%p12%
```

I hope you guys can help me because i really want to play this game with some classmates when i finish this project.

Comment: You code must be incomplete. Where is personage set and path set?

Comment: you mean all the code? because its 883 lines long

Comment: If you can't provide a smaller, reproducible version, then yes.

Comment: You are using the combined system/user environment `%path%` variable wrongly. Use a different variable name for your private use => `MyPath` or whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

The command to "echo" a file contents in DOS is `type`

NOTE: I do not recommend developing any game in DOS script, especially a networked game. You will run in to problems using a file to keep track because only one user can have the file open at a time. All other users will crash while the file is open.

If you want to make a game, use python. It has libraries to do many of the things you want to do.